# How can I tell if an Airflow dag run finished without failing using the Airflow DB?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I want to extract statistics on our Airflow processes using its database. One of these statistics is how many DAG runs are finished smoothly, without any failures and reruns. Doing that using the try_number column of the dag_run table doesn't help, since it also counts automatic retries. I want to count only the cases in which an engineer had to rerun or resume the DAG run.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to get all Dagruns that never had a failed task in them? You can do this by excluding all DAG run_id s that have an entry in the task_failed table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dag_run 
    WHERE run_id NOT IN (
        SELECT run_id 
        FROM dag_run 
        JOIN task_fail USING(run_id)
    )
;
```

This of course would not catch other task states that an engineer might intervene with like marking a task as successful that is stuck in running or a deferred state etc.

One note as of Airflow 2.5.0 you can add notes to DAG and task runs in the UI when manually intervening. Those notes are stored in the tables dag_run_note and task_instance_note.

[image: DAG run note in UI]